# Is there a way to make subheadings in a table and only dynamically sort the main headings in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

For example, say I want to sort the table below by how many points each game had but I want to keep teams under their game subheading.

| Game | Points |
| --- | --- |
| **Game 1** | **6** |
| Team A | 4 |
| Team B | 2 |
| **Game 2** | **13** |
| Team D | 7 |
| Team E | 6 |
| **Game 3** | **12** |
| Team G | 7 |
| Team H | 5 |

So I would turn that into this

| Game | Points |
| --- | --- |
| **Game 2** | **13** |
| Team D | 7 |
| Team E | 6 |
| **Game 3** | **12** |
| Team G | 7 |
| Team H | 5 |
| **Game 1** | **6** |
| Team A | 4 |
| Team B | 2 |

I would be changing the team score by referencing another table in the sheet. And the game score would be the sum of those score cells.

I have very little idea of where to even start with this. Maybe put the subheadings in different columns?

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged Excel 2016 I used old formulas instead of FILTER/SEQUENCE:

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$10,IFERROR(MATCH(LARGE(IF((LEFT($A$2:$A$10,4)="game"),$B$2:$B$10),1+INT((ROW()-2)/3)),$B$2:$B$10,0)+MOD(ROW()-2,3),""))
```

I used this in a cell in row 2 and dragged this to the right and down.

It uses LARGE to check the position of column A starting with `"Game"` with the highest points and uses that for 3 rows and adds 1 row each time. After the third it checks for the position of the next largest +1, +1, etc.

These rows are used within index to return the values from column A and B in the order as stated.

This does not work in case of a tie in total points